# R:: How to get the complete output results without being truncated?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I want to see the output of the classification algorithm that i am applying to my dataset.

I am  using the command summary(fit) to see the output. However the output is getting truncated and could not see the complete output. How can i see the complete output?

```
library(C50)
fit <- C5.0(target ~., data =  train, rules = TRUE)
summary(fit)

class(fit)
C5.0
```

I tried to convert this to a dataframe, however it is not getting converted.

Comment: It's a good idea to explicitly state what packages you are using. I assume you are using the `C50` package. Generally, you can use `str(fit)` to explore the complete structure of any R object.

Comment: @DMC - Thanks for the response. Yes, I am using C50 package. I just want the Rules from the output. I used fit$rules. However the output is messy which i am not able to interpret

Comment: have you tried using `sink()`? Exporting it to a text file might make it better to read

Comment: @Andrelrms - sink() has worked. Thank you very much. If you could post the answer below i will accept it. I never know such an option exist in R. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @Arun, I will post an answer soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment you can use `sink()` here is a little example:

```
library(C50)

data(iris)

fit <- C5.0(Species ~., data =  iris, rules = TRUE)
sink("sink_rules.txt")
summary(fit)
sink()
```